# How to fix gdb error: Cannot access memory at address

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, gdb, qemu

When I debug my linux kernel module using gdb and qemu I get unconsistency results. When I put a breakpoint or disassemble my own fucntion, Sometimes I get "Cannot access memory at address: {function_address}" and **sometimes I get the disassembled code**

I have built an automation script which raises a linux vm using qemu. The script transfers my kernel module files to the vm, builds the kernel module and loads it.
The script retrieves the loaded sections addresses from "/sys/module/{ko name}/sections/" ".text" ".bss" ".data" and then loads the ko file with the retrieved addresses of the sections to gdb.

**I have to mention that I disable kaslr and compile the LKM with debug symbols.**

Then I try to "disas" my own function and its fail sometimes.

Qemu cmdline: sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -hda ~/ubuntu.qcow -m 4096 -kernel /boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-23-generic -append "root=/dev/sda1 nokaslr" -net user,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22 -net nic -snapshot -s

LKM symbols loading cmdline: add-symbol-file ${module_path} ${text} -s .data ${data} -s .bss ${bss}

I expect the output of "disas" command to be the disassembled code, but for example the actual result sometimes is:
**Dump of assembler code for function :
   0xffffffffc0344000 <+0>: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffc0344000**